# windows 7 or Skype ignores microphone's boost at EACH conversation

Tags: windows-7, skype, microphone

Using REaltek codek and Windows 7.

Microphone becomes silent since the begining of every Skype conversation. It forces me to set mic boost on 0db and then again on 20db EVERY single conversation.

How to fix it?